# Get the ID for range with smallest difference

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say that I have a table A. This table has ID, X_value, Y_value. Here is content of table A:

Table A

```
ID X_value Y_value
1  100     150
2  110     170
3  120     190
```

Now, if I'm comparing number **130** with range numbers(X_value - Y_value) I would like to get ID of range with smallest(minimal) difference! If I can name it that way? Right away we see that number **130** will fall into all this ranges, but I need ID of range with smallest(minimal) difference between **130** and numbers of range. To elaborate that difference:

```
For range 1: 130-100=30 and 150-130=20
For range 2: 130-110=20 and 170-130=40
For range 3: 130-120=10 and 190-130=60
```

From this elaboration we see that minimal difference is at third range(that is **10**) so I would like to get ID **3**. What will be a query for this example if I have this table within MySQL db?!

Comment: Can be there two ID with the same minimal differences?

Comment: As a matter of fact, there can not be more than one ID with the same minimal differences. These, so called, ranges are carefully defined so there is no such situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * 
from yourtable
order by case when ABS(x-130)<ABS(y-130) then ABS(x-130) else ABS(y-130) end
limit 1
```

or

```
select id
from
(select id,x from yourtable union select id,y from yourtable) v
order by ABS(x-130) 
limit 1
```

Comment: Your answer was the most suited for my problem. I consider it as an answer and appreciate your help. Thank you podiluska!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
WHERE ID IN
(
    SELECT ID FROM
    (
        SELECT 
          ID,
          130 - x_value xdiff,
          y_value - 130 ydiff
        FROM Table1
        ORDER BY xdiff ASC LIMIT 1
    ) t
)
```

This will give you:

```
ID    X_VALUE    Y_VALUE
3       120       190
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d6e0/5)

Answer (score 2):

Just modified Mahmoud Gamal's query to do the trick:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
WHERE ID IN
(
 SELECT ID FROM
  (
SELECT 
  ID,
  CASE
WHEN (130 - x_value > y_value - 130) THEN y_value - 130
ELSE 130 - x_value
END
FROM Table1
 where 130>=x_value and 130<=y_value
ORDER BY 2 ASC LIMIT 1
    )t)
```

Check it here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/117a0/1